# Is there a list of function shorthand notations, shortcuts, and other various symbols somewhere?

Tags: functions, keyboard

For example how you can use `//` to apply some functions like `Simplify` instead of enclosing the argument in square brackets. Or use `@`. And about a billion other non-word commands that I've seen, but have no idea what they do and didn't even know existed. Sometimes I come across code that looks like someone was has just bashing their head on the keyboard or swearing profusely (_@&%$#,etc). It'd be nice to see them all in one place somewhere.

Comment: Yes there is such a list.  And the whole post is quite useful.


  http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users/25616#25616

Comment: excellent, thank you!